# Django REST Framework: Posting to URL with ID in URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Given the following contrived example, how can I `POST` to a URL with an ID in path and have it resolve the model instance instead of including the model instance in the `POST` body itself?

urls.py

```py
path("api/schools/<int:pk>/student/", views.CreateStudentView.as_view(), name="createStudent")
```

models.py

```py
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(default="", max_length=128)
    mascot = models.CharField(default="", max_length=128)


class StudentModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=128)
    notes = models.CharField(default="", max_length=512)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```py
class CreateStudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name")
```

views.py

```py
class CreateStudentView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateStudentSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
```

I want to be able to `POST` just the new student's first name and last name to the URL to create a new student in my database.  However, because I don't provide a `School` object in the body of my `POST` I get an error.  I was hoping it would be possible for my code to resolve which school I want to add the student to because the URL contains the ID.

I get an error when I `POST` the following body to `/api/schools/1/student/`.  The school with an ID of 1 does exist in the database.

```json
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith"
}
```

```
IntegrityError at /api/schools/1/student/

NOT NULL constraint failed: students_school.school_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by overriding the create method of your `CreateStudentView`. URL parameters are stored in `self.kwargs`, so you can retrieve it from there, and inject it into your serializer:

```
class CreateStudentView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateStudentSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()
        
        # Check if a pk was passed through the url.
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:        
            modified_data = self.request.data.copy()
            modified_data['school'] = self.kwargs.get('pk')
            kwargs["data"] = modified_data
            return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

        # If not mind, move on.
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

Credits to [this article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf-request/), where you can read more about why this works.

Comment: I get the following error on the `kwards["data"]` line: `When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.`

Comment: I fixed the previous issue by doing: `serializer = serializer_class(*args, **kwargs) serializer.is_valid() return serializer`.  However, now when I `POST` I still get the original error that I described in my question.  I think this is because `question` is expected to be a model instance and not an integer ID for the model instance.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so, because if that were the case, you'd get a different error, namely that the type of variable is not correct. Can you inspect what `serializer.validated_data` looks like right after calling serializer.is_valid()?